# Couchdb with Clouseau plugin is taking more storage than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

I've been using an AWS instance with CouchDb as a backup to IBM's Cloudant database of my application (using replication).

Everything seems to work fine but I've been noticing the permanent increase of Volume size in the AWS instance (it gets full all the time with the annoying problem of increasing a volume when there's no space in the partition).

[Actual use of storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u165O.png)

The data in the screenshot is using almost 250 GB. I would like to know the possible reason for this issue, my guess is that the Clouseau plugin is using more space to enable the search index queries.

As I'm not an expert with this database, Anyone could explain to me why this is happening and how could I mitigate the issue?

My best regards!

Comment: As this is not a programming-related question, it is off-topic. ServerFault would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi @Flimzy I think you're right, I will move it to SeverFault, thanks for the feedback (I'm a newbie trying to get his first points XD).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only backing up a Cloudant database to a CouchDB instance via replication, you should not need Clouseau enabled.
Clouseau is only required for search indices and if you are not doing queries on your backup database you can disable Clouseau in there. The indices are not backed up in the replication.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply, I do need the indices that's why I enabled Clouseau. Actually I m wondering if that's the cause of the extra space used by my database.

Comment: @NicolasMauricioCuadrado : But then your CouchDB instance is not an actual backup that you would only need when your Cloudant database is unavailable (or in any disaster scenario). Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @bessbd you're right, it is more an auxiliary DB that I want to query regularly using search indexes.